# Metallic bang sound when moving off

Tags: suspension, alignment, parking

Honda Civic coupe vti 1999.

When moving off today just as I was manoeuvring out I heard a metallic bang sound which sounds like ‘dang’ noise if that makes any sense.

I made nothing off it drove out and quickly realised vehicle was pulling to left like an alignment problem.  I also realised a grumbling sound which was to the left of the car too.

I only went forward or turned right i was in a tight spot bikes in front and back.  I’m not sure why it was so Loud and caused the car to become misaligned. Could I have hit the kerb, how so?

At the same time why is there a rumbling sound kind of like marbles rolling around at times?  Perhaps it’s not an alignment issue, I’ve never heard a grumbling/marble rolling sound accompany a misalignment before.  could some suspension part have gone bad?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your suspension coil springs could have snapped.  That would account for the bang sound.  The coil spring could now be rubbing against the tyre giving a rumbling sound. This issue would account for the pulling to one side too.

My advice would be to not drive the car until you have identified what is wrong, it could be very dangerous,

Comment: Would I be ok to drive it slowly to a garage say not exceeding 20mph in and around London? Did an oil change mechanic didn’t notice but then maybe he didn’t look.  If the suspension proves to be ok would u say it’s just an alignment issue?  Thanks

Comment: "oil change" and "mechanic" should not be used together.

Comment: If the spring is pressing on the tyre, the car shouldn’t be moved.  Are you able to take the wheel off to have a look?  It obviously could be something else, but this is what comes to my mind.

Comment: I’m in the middle of nowhere and don’t have any tools.  I’ll full lock it and see if I notice any spring abnormality and post it.  Assuming the problem is as you think, what could happen on route to garage if driven slowly?  Thanks

Comment: Worst case: the spring cuts through the tire and locks up the wheel completely, and the unexpected sharp left turn kills somebody.  Next worst case: a police patrol sees you driving at an abnormally slow speed, stops you assuming you might be drunk or on drugs, discovers the problem, gets the car towed away as being unsafe and prosecutes you for driving an unroadworthy vehicle. Personally, I would blame that new oil cap for everything :)

Comment: Have you marked this as correct because you have seen a broken spring? If not you should wait for other suggestions first.

Comment: @HandyHowie no.  I marked it as correct because it showed me the danger I might be in and encouraging safety while I had been trying tI now know what t is though, I guess I’ll see if anyone else can figure it out.

Comment: Are you saying you now know what the issues is?

Comment: @handyhowie I do now.  One rear wheel bearing has gone bad.  I know the marble sound can be attributed to a wheel bearing but not sure why the metallic bang sound happened.  Is this also a symptom of a bad bearing?  Thanks

Comment: One of the rollers probably jot jammed then quickly moved, causing the bang.  Glad you have solved the issue.